# Can I show author and commit log in diff inside bitbucket?

Tags: git, bitbucket, blame, git-blame

### Here is my context:

I am working in a repository with two branches: master and develop.

All the team makes local changes in their code and after finishing their task they merge their commits into the develop branch.

After some time, a Pull Request is made to the master branch. **Here is where my question rises:**

**I have different authors and commits made all in the same pull request. When I look the diff in the Bitbucket GUI,  how I can I know which person made which change in each file or line? (so I can tag that person and deny the task  equivalent of that commit -- when there is a problem)**

Right now, the only solution is to go commit by commit to see the changes, but it doesn't seem very practical. Is there any conceptual problem in my workflow?

Comment: If I am getting your question right, you should be looking into `git-blame`. Or have you tried that already?

Comment: IDEs usually have an 'annotate' feature as well which does basically the same thing

Comment: I was trying to use the same interface to facilitate the process. With git-blame I would have to go out bitbucket to the prompt and check each file who changed it. Same thing to the IDE, it would have to change all the code review to the IDE interface not allowing to tag people and comments

Comment: You might want to take a look at difflame, a tool I worked on that brings together blame and diff output. Might be close to what you are looking for. It's not perfect... let me know how it goes https://github.com/eantoranz/difflame

Comment: Blame has been available on Bitbucket server since version 4.6. Not sure what version you are on: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/bitbucket-server-4-6-release-notes-827109988.html

Comment: @eeijlar, The only way to get blame is opening each file, looking at the source code, and then clicking in the annotate button. I can not do that for each file change in a pull request to check the authors. It would take way too much time